# How to fix issue in UPDATE with multi-node cassandra cluster

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am having a cassandra cluster with 2 nodes, in that case if one of the nodes goes down I am unable to do update operation in cql once both are up I am able to do so

Answer (score 0):

Having only 2 nodes for a Cassandra cluster isn't a great choice. However, as that's what you have, if you can't manipulate the data because a node is down, that means that your client consistency level (CL) is higher than the number of available nodes to store the data (that would apply no matter how many nodes you have in cassandra). So my guess is that your client CL is set to either some quorum level (LOCAL_QUORUM OR QUORUM) or ALL. Any QUORUM would = 2, which in your case would fail due to only having a single node available. You could set your client CL=ONE or LOCAL_ONE and it should work. Cassandra is designed for redundancy/high availability so the fact that you can't even have a single node down is not an ideal setup for Cassandra. If it were me, I would add another node. Then you can have a QUORUM setting AND still have an unavailable node.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response.... I missed to say one thing that all updates were not failed  but the one with IF EXISTS is failing and i am having consistency as ONE and replication factor as 2. I tried the same with consistency as LOCAL_ONE as well as ANY but I could not achieve... I tried by increasing Replication factor also... the error i got is "All hosts in current policy attempted and were either unavailable or failed"

Comment: What if you don't use the "IF EXISTS" clause? Setting your RF higher than the number of nodes doesn't do anything (can only replicate to as many nodes as you have - in your case, 2). I wonder if the "IF EXISTS" is causing the failure because maybe your data is out of sync on each node (maybe the record doesn't exist on the node that is running but does on the node that is down). Can you check that out as well (do a local_one query on the record/row on each node)?

Comment: If I am not using IF EXISTS I am able to update, of course what you are saying is happening I think....  Node which has data is down and one that is up is not having it.  But my doubt is we are having RF 2 with 2 nodes so data must be there in both the nodes then why we are getting such error...

Comment: Even though you have a RF of 2, the nodes can become out of sync if any of them are down for too long. What you could try is to ensure both nodes are running and then run a repair on both nodes to ensure they're in sync. Then retry your test.